# React/Redux application strange behaviour

Tags: reactjs, redux, profiling

I have found strange behaviour in my React app. I was investigating perfomance issues and used "timings" in Chrome Profiller. Here I found that one of my actions, which is not updating store, produces a lot of "React tree reconciliations".

This action is dispatched from redux middleware, but there are no reducers for this action type. So action doesn't change Redux store, but some of connected React components firing "Reconciliation". Action is dispatched from Redux middleware after some Promise resolves. What can cause this?

[image: Profiler results]